# Node app not working in openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, hapi.js

I am running a HAPI node server to serve my js codebase. The server seems to run fine. However hitting The url throws a 503 error.

```
const store = configureStore();
const initialState = store.getState();

//from environment variable grab our data and the backend data
const hostname = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
const port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT;
const restHostUrl = process.env.SERVER_URL || "localhost";
const restHostProtocol = process.env.SERVER_PROTOCOL || "http";
const restHostPort = process.env.SERVER_PROTOCOL || "1337";

//creating hapi server - popping my cherry with hapi on this one - im more of an express kinda guy.
const server = new Server();
server.connection({host: hostname, port: port});
server.register(
  [
    h2o2,
    inert,
    // WebpackPlugin
  ],
  (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  server.start(() => {
    console.info("==> ✅  Server is listening");
    console.info("==>   Go to " + server.info.uri.toLowerCase());
  });
});
...
```

Comment: you should put an error in server start callback and listen to it?  What is the value of hostname and port? Also you are not registering any routes in this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly Issue. Webpack was transforming process.env.openshift to something else int dist/server.js which was causing it to use localhost and hence the issue.